# Error while importing functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called Comment, and I'm calling it in another component called BlogPost.

I imported Comment in BlogPost like so:

```
import Comment from './Comment';
```

When I run the app, I get the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Comment`.
```

I found other posts that had the same issue as me, and I tried what they suggested, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The comment component:

```
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Moment } from "react-moment";

function Comment(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={props.comment.profileImg} alt=""/>
                <div>
                <Typography>
                    <b>{props.comment.displayName}</b>
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">
                    <Moment format="MMM. D, YYYY">{props.comment.date}</Moment>
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body1">
                    {props.comment.body}
                </Typography>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Comment;
```

The BlogPost component:

```
return (
        <div>
            <Appbar />
            <div className="root">
                <DetailCard post={isPropStateNull ? post : props.location.state.post}/>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
                        <DetailContent post={isPropStateNull ? post : props.location.state.post}/>
                        <AddComment />
                        {comments.length !== 0 ? comments.map((currentComment) => <Comment comment={ currentComment }/>) : <div>ha</div>}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                        <OtherPosts otherPosts={otherPosts}/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Before anything, strongly recommend a fresh restart to the local server

Comment: Tried that, didn't work :(

Comment: I think problem in Typography, please try again by commenting typography lines, in Comments.js

Comment: make sure both components are in the same folder.

Comment: RiTeSh, you're correct. Commenting out Typography got rid of the error, but I still don't understand why I was getting that error in the first place.

Comment: Then share the Typography component and let's find out!

Comment: Typography is not a custom component, it's a part of material-ui. What I don't understand is, I've used Typography in the other components and it worked just fine, yet when I use it in Comment.js, it gives me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was an error in importing Moment.

Instead of importing it like this:

```
import { Moment } from "react-moment";
```

I should've done it like this:

```
import Moment from "react-moment";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

`import Moment from 'react-moment';`

from

`import { Moment } from 'react-moment';`

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-bush-ek9cg?file=/src/index.js)